# Understanding B2C magic link

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have an asp.net core application which uses a custom policy for Azure B2C local accounts and social accounts. Now we want to allow access for some pages of the application for users, which are not in B2C directory and we want to send these users a link in an email to give them temporarily access.

We followed the instructions for "magic links" in B2C: we can send a link in an email and we are sucessfully redirected by B2C to our application with an "id_token" in the query string.

What we don't understand: should we check the returned id token ourselves and start a session for the user ourselves, or can we use the asp.net authentication middleware so that the user is handled like an "authenticated" user and we can use claims to allow them limited access only? We cannot find an example application that uses the returned "id_token" to start an authenticated session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an MSAL client-side library, it would do all this for you.

From the client side, it would be pretty much the same as authenticating.

Comment: At the moment we do not understand the meaning of "state" on this page (at the end):
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link
"The authentication libraries create a state when the authentication flow begins from your application."
We receive in our application the "id_token" from B2C but get error message "message.state is null or empty" and are not able to solve it.

Comment: Hi Torsten, were you able to get an understanding on the above. We are also trying a similar approach. We have an id_token_hint and our policy creates a valid id_token. But from the id_token how is a valid session created.